# Why does this code not update the content of the label every second but rather wait 6 seconds and then show the last word? (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, label, thread-sleep

I wanted to display an array of strings in a label and every second one word should show up and after one second the next. I think this code does the job but the label does not refresh until the for loop is completed. Can anyone help me pls?

```
        string[] listOfWords = RemoveCharacters(enteredText);

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfWords.Length; i++)
        {
            word.Content = listOfWords[i];
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: I am new to coding so the answer might as well be very easy...

Comment: The answer is easy - the UI won't update until the method ends is the short answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to change it?